# apache2 web server works on localhost but can't go live

Tags: webserver, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

My website cannot go live!

```
The following is my web server setup.

1.  Rogers modem – Hitron CODA-4582

2.  Port Forwarding
Application Name    Public      Private     Protocol    Local IP Address
HTTP                80 – 80     800 – 800   TCP         192.168.0.201
HTTPS               443 – 443   883 – 883   TCP         192.168.0.201

3.  Operating System - ubuntu 16.0.4
Apache2 Sever /etc/apache2.conf file.
I modified two things.
a.  Uncommented the line ServerRoot “/etc/apache2”
b.  Appended one line at the end of the file: ServerName my_rogers_IP_address.
I executed a command: sudo app info “Apache Full”
The output is 
Profile: Apache Full
Title: Web Server (HTTP,HTTPS)
Description: Apache v2 is the next generation of the omnipresent Apache web
server.

Ports:
  80,443/tcp

Then, I executed another command: sudo ufw allow in “Apache Full”
```

I thought I have done what I needed to do. So, I opened up the browser for testing. It only works for 127.0.0.1 or localhost. It won’t work if I enter http://my_rogers_IP_address.
Can someone give me a pointer?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the apacheserver to a host that can actually host your website. Localhost is just a local loop between your computer's machine and the server. I would recommend using Heroku, or Cloud9, which is free. Additionally, you could buy a static IP for your site to use, however, this is not cost-effective. It is up to you whether you have the funds or just want to do this for fun.

Comment: Thank you! However, at this moment, I just want to have this thing done temporarily for experimenting. Therefore, I just use my dynamic routable IP address! I absolutely understood what you said. I use no-ip services with a domain name for my another site without any problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
I got my problem solved!!
It is my bad! Everything is fine except the private port setting.
The private port must be within the public port range.
Everything is working fine now. Hope this can help someone else.
Good day!
```